# What do you mean by ||x|| in hyper plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am reading my linear algebra notes, I don't understand `||x||` meaning?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Notation ​ ​

Comment: that has many definition, not able to co-relate exactly which one.

Comment: It's general on purpose I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Vert x\Vert$ is the norm of $x$. Intuitively it's the "length of the vector", or the "distance of the point from the origin".

In your case, you're implicitly working with $\Vert x\Vert = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+ x_n^2}$. You'll see that this is pythagoras' theorem to get the length of a diagonal in a right angled triangle in $n$-dimensions. There are other ways you can define $\Vert x\Vert$, but the one defined above enables you to have a notion of angles in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's the standard unless otherwise stated.

If you think of it as the distance of the point from the origin, it's clear that "$\Vert x \Vert ≤ r$ for all $x\in T$" is a sensible definition for boundedness, because it's saying "no points in $T$ are more than $r$ away from the origin".